# how to subscript when there is a cap on mathematical expression?

Tags: math-mode, equations, subscripts, inline

The following equation is typed using MS word:

[image: typed using MSword]

When I tried to type same using LaTeX with subscript `_i` ended up with this result because there is a cap above subscript "beta". The LaTeX output is this:

[image: latex output]

So help me to type this equation in LaTeX. The rest of all subscripts worked well.

I used the following code:

```
$\left|\mathop{\Sigma }\limits^{\wedge } _{\mathop{\beta }\limits^{\wedge } _{\left(i\right)} } \right|$ 
and $\left|\mathop{\Sigma }\limits^{\wedge } _{\mathop{\beta }\limits^{\wedge } } \right|$, 
where $\left(\mathop{\Sigma }\limits^{\wedge } _{\mathop{\beta }\limits^{\wedge } _{\left(i\right)} } \right)$
```

Comment: Can you give your actual code ?

Comment: @Sulthan please update your question instead. Also don't use `\left...\right` in inline mas as you can see they get too big.

Comment: it's unclear to me whether `\Sigma` is meant here, or `\sum`.  in any event, specifying `\limits` in in-line math is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do get rid of all `\mathop` directives (it's not correct to treat `\Sigma` and `\beta` as "math operators" -- they're just "ordinary" symbols) and all `\limits` directives (you definitely want to set the subscripts to the side of the main symbol, not immediately below them), and do use `\hat` and `\widehat` directives instead of `\wedge` to place "hat" symbols on top of `\beta` and `\Sigma`, respectively.

Furthermore, the sizes of the "fences" generated by `\left` and `\right` seem too large, typographically speaking. I would recommend creating `\big`-sized fences.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% for "\DeclarePairedDelimiter" macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert % "absolute value" macro

\begin{document}
$\abs[\big]{\widehat{\Sigma} _{\hat{\beta}_{(i)} } }$ 
and $\abs[\big]{\widehat{\Sigma} _{\hat{\beta} } }$, 
where $\bigl(\widehat{\Sigma} _{\hat{\beta}_{(i)}} \bigr)$
\end{document}
```